# Selenium find attribute value (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I would like to get all attribute values names 'href' from a website, there are like 10 of them. I have successfully got one using the following method:

```
url = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/span/a"))).get_attribute("href")
```

The problem with this is it's only giving back one not all of them. I have tried to go by ID but it doesn't return anything:

```
url = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "a"))).get_attribute("href")
```

Also, the other href values are located in different xpaths:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/div/div[1]/span/a
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/ul/li[3]/div/div[1]/span/a
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/ul/li[4]/div/div[1]/span/a
```

Here's my element:

```
<a ph-tevent="job_click" ref="linkEle" href.bind="getUrl(linkEle, 'job', eachJob, '', eachJob.jobUrl)" data-ph-at-id="job-link" data-ph-id="ph-page-element-page20-CRUCUZ" class="au-target" au-target-id="181" ph-click-ctx="job" ph-tref="12313123213" ph-tag="ph-search-results-v2" href="https://hyperlink.com" data-ph-at-job-title-text="title" data-ph-at-job-location-text="Unknown" data-ph-at-job-location-area-text="asd" data-ph-at-job-category-text="Manufacturing" data-access-list-item="2" data-ph-at-job-id-text="A123124" data-ph-at-job-type-text="Regular" data-ph-at-job-industry-text="Manufacturing" data-ph-at-job-post-date-text="2021-12-09T00:00:00.000Z" data-ph-at-job-seqno-text="ASD212ASFS" aria-label="Senior Manager"> 
<div class="job-title" data-ph-id="ph-page-element-page20-0Mi3Ce"> 
<!--anchor--> 
<!--anchor--> 
<span data-ph-id="ph-page-element-page20-PLxqta">Senior Manager </span> 
</div><!--anchor--> </a>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: try using CSS_SELECTOR instead of ID
find_elements_by_css_selector("a") returns a list of elements, then iterate over that list and get_attribute("href")

Comment: @vboxer00 Can you update the question with the HTML of another position similar to _Senior Manager_ so we can find the common attributes for the desired elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding more than one web element, you should either use `find_elements` or if you are using **Explicit waits** then you can use `presence_of_all_elements_located` or `visibility_of_all_elements_located`.

Based on the HTML that you've shared, if

this **css**

```
a[ph-tevent='job_click'][ref='linkEle']
```

or this **xpath**

```
//a[@ph-tevent='job_click' and @ref='linkEle']
```

represent all the nodes, to check below are the steps:

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **all desired nodes** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `elements` are getting **highlighted** or not.

If they are then the below code should work:

```
for ele in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@ph-tevent='job_click' and @ref='linkEle']"):
    print(ele.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Possibly your xpath won't compile due to invalid syntax. You need an _`and`_ between the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the value of the *href* attributes using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631116/python-selenium-wait-for-several-elements-to-load/64770041#64770041) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[ph-tevent='job_click'][ref='linkEle'][data-ph-at-id='job-link'][ph-click-ctx='job'][href]")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@ph-tevent='job_click' and @ref='linkEle'][@data-ph-at-id='job-link' and @ph-click-ctx='job'][@href]")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```